# Probably of Fukushima like event

Tags: probability, statistics

I was reading an article where an author was discussing the relative safety of power plants. In the article there was statement that a tsunami with a wave of 15 meters happens once every 5000 years.

One of the commenter said that if we assume that the lifetime of an reactor is 50 years the probability of similar event is `50/5000 = 0.01` or 1%. And knowing that the are 23 nuclear power plants that operate in a high risk tsunami areas, the probability that it happens in one of them is `1 - (1-0.01)^23 = 20%`

It seems to be too high to be true. What is wrong and what would be more accurate estimation?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that these are independent events.  I'd interpret  that "once in $5000$ years" to refer to any tsunami hitting Japan, not just one specific spot.  But, in any case, this really isn't something for pure math to decide. More of a hard actuarial problem.

Comment: Why does it seem too high to be true? It describes the probability of something that actually turned out to occur. How can _any_ estimate "seem too high to be true"?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of having a tsunami with a wave of 15 meters in a certain year is $\frac{1}{5000}=2\times 10^{-4}$. If $X$ is the number of such waves in the lifetime of a reactor (50 years), then we can model $X$ as a Poisson-distributed random variable with rate $50\times 2\times 10^{-4}=0.01$. The probability that a reactor experiences at least one such event is $$\mathbb P(X\ge 1)=1-\mathbb P(X=0)=1-e^{-0.01}=0.009950$$
In calculating the probability that the event happens to one of the 23 reactors, you assumed that the events are independent, i.e. a tsunami affecting one of the reactors is not in any way related to another tsunami affecting another one, which is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

Your math is right, but there's one catch - the $1\%$ probability, at least to my understanding, applies to a tsunami in Japan as a *whole* rather than just near power plants. The real probability is then far less, because the chances that a tsunami hits a plant is far less than $1\%.$